# Proper tag nice for eventually obsolete concepts in biology?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I am revising the tag system of our site and have discovered the [history](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), [which](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) has the following description:

> Questions regarding early biology

This is a little bit misguiding for me, because I understand it as if somebody asks about the concepts that were simetimes considered correct and valid, but not anymore (getting obsolete, deprecated or even proved wrong), for instance the Lamarck's theory of evolution.

Same time, the question about the history of biology are not necessarily related to those concepts. There is a question about good textbooks on history of biology which is also tagged as "history", even though in the question it is clear that it is not the early biology that is requested there.

Maybe we should create a new tag for eventually invalid knowledge? Something like "obsolete", "believed" etc?

Comment: (hint: you can simply write `[tag:history]` to add a link to tags)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Thanks, I was looking for it almost half an hour before giving up and publishing it this way.

Comment: actually I don't know how one could find this, searching for tag and link yields anything... I think I spotted it at [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/146482)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the four questions tagged [history](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) at present, it strikes me that none of them are actually asking about deprecated or obsolete concepts.  So perhaps the history tag should remain named as it is currently and have its description modified to something along the lines of

> Questions relating to how the field of biology has developed over time (including the discussion of theories now considered incorrect).

#### This was put in last month, do people think that the text as it currently reads is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the **History** tag explanation can be changed to: chronological discovery, description, and collection of biological events; and a the tag for obsolete concepts in biology can be added, named **Obsolete concepts**.